# Obtain an OracleDataSource in SpringBoot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, oracle11g

Is it possible to retrieve a OracleDataSource from the default SpringBoot 2 Hikari connection pool using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate object?
Using Java 8, Oracle 11g (ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.jar) and gradle
This is what i've tried.

```
@Repository
public class MyClass{

@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate  jdbcTemplate;

public void myMethod(){
try{
    //OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();                                            // This works but is obviously not Spring
    OracleDataSource ods = (OracleDataSource) jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource();   // This fails

    ods.setURL(url);
    ods.setUser(user);
    ods.setPassword(pass);

    ...
    catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${ORA_HOST}:${ORA_PORT}/${ORA_SID}
spring.datasource.username=${USER}
spring.datasource.password=${PASS}
```

Error message:

```
In Exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (or neccessary). The easiest way is to unwrap() a connection object, which has already  connected to the dB:

```
Connection conn =  this.jdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a query like, how are you able to get OracleConnection.class, because in my case I get squiggly line underneath OracleConnection.class and there are no packages available to import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).